# Twisted ssh server authentication using keys

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.conch

Here is a simple twisted application:

```python
from twisted.cred import checkers, portal
from twisted.conch import manhole, manhole_ssh
from twisted.conch.insults import insults

from twisted.application import service, internet
from twisted.internet import endpoints, reactor


def makeManholeService(namespace):
    checker = checkers.InMemoryUsernamePasswordDatabaseDontUse(
        username="password")

    realm = manhole_ssh.TerminalRealm()
    realm.chainedProtocolFactory = lambda: insults.ServerProtocol(
                                        manhole.ColoredManhole, namespace)
    prt = portal.Portal(realm, [checker])
    factory = manhole_ssh.ConchFactory(prt)

    endp = endpoints.serverFromString(reactor, 'tcp:6022')

    manholeService = internet.StreamServerEndpointService(endp, factory)
    return manholeService


application = service.Application("my app")
manholeService = makeManholeService({'foo': 'bar'})
manholeService.setServiceParent(application)
```

We can connect to it with ssh:

```
$ ssh username@localhost -p 6022
username@localhost's password:

>>> foo
'bar'
>>>
```

Now I want to replace `InMemoryUsernamePasswordDatabaseDontUse` such that the server can authenticate users, who identify themselves using rsa/dsa keys.

Do I have to implement a checker?

For example, I have some public keys listed in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. The SSH server should reject all connections, except those that can be verified using public keys in that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to make a checker.  But there are building blocks you can use within Conch that should make it pretty easy.  Ying Li has an example project, "ess" ("SSH" without the "SH") that [implements some checkers](https://github.com/cyli/ess/blob/master/ess/checkers.py) that you might be interested in checking out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. At first I looked at `twisted.cred.checkers`. Now I found that there is also `twisted.conch.checkers`, that contains `SSHPublicKeyDatabase`. It looks like what I need. You re

Comment: `twisted.conch.checkers.SSHPublicKeyDatabase` looks very similar to `ess.checkers.SSHPublicKeyChecker`, which you pointed me to. Now I am confused. Isn't `twisted.conch.checkers.SSHPublicKeyDatabase` sufficient?

Comment: The difference is that in Ess there is an explicit mapping object for separating out the `getpwnam` API call which locates a user's UNIX home directory.  You can see Ess has separate classes, `AuthorizedKeysFilesMapping` and `UNIXAuthorizedKeysFiles`, which look up authorized keys from a mapping in memory and from the UNIX account database API, respectively.

Comment: In fact, this useful functionality in ess was contributed by cyli back to Twisted, so in the upcoming release of Twisted (14.1, which is not out yet) you'll be able to use `twisted.conch.checkers.SSHPublicKeyChecker` instead, and `SSHPublicKeyDatabase` will be deprecated.